# Getting strange results from wxPython WebView

Tags: python, webview, wxpython

I'm making a Huffington Post RSS feed aggregator in wxPython, but I've run into some trouble. In the program there are two panels in a main wx.Frame: One shows a list of all articles and the other will show a web view of the article that the user selects. I haven't gotten to that part yet, so I decided to just test the web view widget by loading Google. However when I do this, I'm getting some strange results. Here is the relevant code:

```
hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

listPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
htmlPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(htmlPanel)
browser.LoadURL("http://www.google.com")

hbox.Add(listPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
hbox.Add(htmlPanel, 2, wx.EXPAND)

self.SetAutoLayout(True)
self.SetSizer(hbox)
self.Layout()
```

And here is a picture of what I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go3hS.png

I seem to get a text box in the upper left corner, possibly a google search box? No clue what it is or why I'm getting this. If anybody happens to see where I've gone wrong, I would greatly appreciate the help.

**EDIT:**

Here is some runnable code that shows the problem:

```
import wx
import wx.html2

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        listPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER) #This is the panel where the news articles would be shown
        htmlPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER) #This is the panel where the web view would be shown

        browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(htmlPanel) #I create the new web view here with the htmlPanel as its parent
        browser.LoadURL("http://www.google.com") #And then I load Google here

        hbox.Add(listPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND) #Then I add both panels to the frame. Not sure where I went wrong.
        hbox.Add(htmlPanel, 2, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.Layout()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None, title='What is this box? HELP!', size=(800,480))
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you create a small, runnable example? This looks right to me, but I can't really help without some runnable code. Is this running on a Mac?

Comment: Posted the code to run, leaving out all the RSS jargon. And yes, this is running on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code doesn't work is because the webview widget isn't in a sizer of its own. Thus it doesn't know to expand. If you do add it to a sizer, it works. See below:

```
import wx
import wx.html2

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        htmlSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        listPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER) #This is the panel where the news articles would be shown
        htmlPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER) #This is the panel where the web view would be shown

        browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(htmlPanel) #I create the new web view here with the htmlPanel as its parent
        browser.LoadURL("http://www.google.com") #And then I load Google here
        htmlSizer.Add(browser, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        htmlPanel.SetSizer(htmlSizer)

        hbox.Add(listPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND) #Then I add both panels to the frame. Not sure where I went wrong.
        hbox.Add(htmlPanel, 2, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.Layout()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None, title='What is this box? HELP!', size=(800,480))
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the problem. Instead of creating a panel and then trying to put the web view into the panel, I just made the parent of the web view self and added that to the frame rather than the second panel. However if anyone would still like to tell me why the initial solution I tried didn't work, I would appreciate it.